# Jquery change function seems to work but doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have 2 radio buttons with jquery code that rebuilds a dropdownlist with just the options that they choose. I have the code below and it goes to the proper method and the method to build the select list works properly and after the method is finished, the dropdownlist items don't change at all. Everything seems to be correct but it just doesn't work. Does anyone have any ideas?

**View**

```
$('#singleSpacingRadio').change(function () {
        var url = "/Home/NumberOfPagesList?id=" + $('#singleSpacingRadio').val();

        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            var items = "<option>--Test--</option>";
            $.each(data, function (i, numberOfPages) {
                items += "<option value='" + numberOfPages.Value + "'>" + numberOfPages.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $("#numberOfPagesList").html(items);
        });
    });

    $('#doubleSpacingRadio').change(function () {
        var url = "/Home/NumberOfPagesList?id=" + $('#doubleSpacingRadio').val();

        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            var items = "<option>--Test--</option>";
            $.each(data, function (i, numberOfPages) {
                items += "<option value='" + numberOfPages.Value + "'>" + numberOfPages.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $("#numberOfPagesList").html(items);
        });
    });

<div class="row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Spacing, "Spacing:")
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Spacing, "Single", new { id = "singleSpacingRadio" }) Single
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Spacing, "Double", new { id = "doubleSpacingRadio" }) Double
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult NumberOfPagesList(string id)
    {
        var numberOfPagesList = from n in NumberOfPages.GetNumberOfPages()
                          where n.Spacing == id
                          select n;

        if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return Json(new SelectList(numberOfPagesList.ToArray(), "numberOfPagesValue", "numberOfPagesName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Contact");
        }
    }

public class NumberOfPages
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Spacing { get; set; }

    public static IQueryable<NumberOfPages> GetNumberOfPages()
    {
        return new List<NumberOfPages>
        {
            new NumberOfPages
            {
                Name = "1 Page (Approx. 550 Words)",
                Value = "1",
                Spacing = "Single"
            },
            new NumberOfPages
            {
                Name = "1 Page (Approx. 275 Words)",
                Value = "1",
                Spacing = "Double"
            },
            new NumberOfPages
            {
                Name = "50 Pages (Approx. 13750 Words)",
                Value = "50",
                Spacing = "Double"
            }
        }.AsQueryable();
    }
```

Comment: Try to debug the javascript. Are there any console errors?

Comment: When ever the `$('#singleSpacingRadio').change()` event occurs, the `$('#doubleSpacingRadio').change()` event also fires so your just doing the same thing over and over.

Comment: How is that possible? It should just do each event separately I thought anyway

Comment: Its a radio button group. When one is selected the other one is unselected - both fire the change event!

Comment: i don't know what `asp.net` exactly generates here - maybe you can show us the resulting `html` as well?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I know that they are a radio button group but I set a different id to each one so that wouldn't happen

Comment: The id's have nothing to do with it. I'll post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the html to

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Spacing, "Single", new { @class = "spacing", id="single" })
<label for="single">Single</label>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Spacing, "Double", new { @class = "spacing", id="double" })
<label for="double">Double</label>
```

and the script to

```
$('.spacing').click(function() {
  var select = $("#numberOfPagesList");
  select.empty().append($('<option></option>').val('').text('--Test--'));
  var url = '@Url.Action("NumberOfPagesList", "Home")';
  $.getJSON(url, { id: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
      select.append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).text(item.Name));
    });
  });
});
```

Note also you do not need to return convert your collection to a `SelectList` and only the following is required

```
return Json(numberOfPagesList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: I tried this code exactly as how you wrote it but I'm getting syntax errors for the script I mean @sStephenMuecke

Comment: Sorry, missed a right brace in the `$.getJSON` line

Comment: I missed that right brace as well. I fixed that and the action seems to work but it is displayed completely wrong now and when I click on one of the radio buttons, it now gives me a dropdownlist with every option being completely blank. I'm going to try to put a screenshot on here

Comment: Sorry again, it should be `.text(item.Name)` since that's the property name of `NumberOfPages`

Comment: Thank you very much! You did things a bit differently but I can see how it works now

Comment: Just wanted to show you some 'best practice' - e.g. never hard code urls (always use `@Url.Action()`, use `<label>`'s associated with controls for accessibiliy