# Preferred way to refresh page content from SQL in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to .NET MVC and would like some advice on refreshing page content from the database prior to the form submission.  Submitting the entire form works without issue and successfully writes to the database.

On the form shown below I would like to query the database for a value keyed into the PartId field when the user clicks the Search button.  Ideally this would happen without a page refresh.

Walkthrough:

1. User keys in part
2. User clicks Search
3. Page fetches all parts from database containing the entered value (dynamically with no page refresh)
4. User is prompted with a list if more than one part if found
5. User completes form and then clicks Create

What is the best way in MVC 4 to perform this?  I'm used to working with button click events so just looking for some direction...

Thanks.

### Form (picture)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDFWT.jpg

### Controller

```
    public ActionResult ConfirmPartNumber(string searchString)
    { 
        // Get part number from SQL database
        // If more than one part found, prompt user with modal to from list

    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Count count)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            count.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            db.Counts.Add(count);
            db.SaveChanges();

            count.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            count.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
            count.UsernameCreatedBy = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            count.UsernameModifiedBy = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(count);
    }
```

### Form

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PartId)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PartId)

        <input type="button" value="Search" /> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Use javascript/jquery and handle the buttons click event to pass the search text in a ajax call to a method and either return a partial view or Json that can be used to update the DOM

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke, can you provide an example of this?

Comment: [This example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990987/jquery-change-function-seems-to-work-but-doesnt-do-anything/26991774#26991774) handles the change event of a dropdown, passes its selected value to a method that returns Json which is used to populate another select.

Comment: Perhaps you could also consider an [autocomplete control](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) or cascading dropdowns to display friendly part names rather than part numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I think best option probably is to use AJAX calls in response to button events.

Your AJAX calls query the database from a server action and return the response to your client code, where you can insert them on your page without a full reload or a form post

Comment: Do you have an example of what the markup would be for this approach?